# Mesclar dois array's recursivamente sem adicionar novas chaves

Tags: php, array, merge

alguém tem alguma dica para mesclar dois array's porém o segundo deve substituir os valores do primeiro recursivamente porém somente das chaves que existir no primeiro, isso é, os valores a mais que existir no segundo não podem ser incluídos no primeiro. array_merge_recursive e array_replace_recursive não atendem porque eles incluem os valores do segundo no primeiro. Já tentei algumas coisas porém até o momento sem uma solução de fato, abaixo uma das formas que já tentei porém não consegui ainda para multidimensional.

```
<?php

function popule($default, $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $d) {
        if (is_array($d)) {
            $more_array = array_filter($d, 'is_array');
            if (count($more_array) > 0) {
                $d = popule($default, $d);
            }

            $keys_remove = array_diff_key($d, $default);

            $data[$key] = array_diff_key($d, $keys_remove);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

$default = array(
    'product_id' => 0,
    'own_id' => 0,
    'name' => '',
    'variation' => array(
        'sku' => 1
    )
);

$data[] = array(
    'product_id' => rand(),
    'own_id' => rand(),
    'name' => 'teste',
    'key_extra' => '5a4sd5teste',
    'variation' => array(
        'sku' => 1
    )
);

print_r(popule($default, $data));
```

O resultado que gostaria, seria conforme o exemplo abaixo

```
<?php
$default = array(
    'product_id' => 0,
    'name' => '',
    'variation' => array(
        'sku' => 1
    )
);

$data[] = array(
    'product_id' => rand(),
    'name' => 'teste',
    'key_extra' => 4545,
    'variation' => array(
        'sku' => 10,
        'key1' => 4545,
        'key2' => 4545,
    )
);

// Resultado Esperado, foi mesclado $default em $data substuindo somente as chaves presentes em $default, as demais foram ignoradas
$data[] = array(
    'product_id' => 5465454,
    'name' => 'teste',
    'variation' => array(
        'sku' => 10
    )
);
```

Foi resolvido com a solução apresentada abaixo pelo JrD, para meu caso que é uma coleção de dados, ficou assim:

```
<?php 
$data[] = array();
$data[] = array();
// .
// .
// .
$data[] = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $_data) {
    $copy_default = $default;

    popule($copy_default, $_data);

    $data[$key] = $copy_default;
}
```

Comment: O seu modelo de array é exatamente esse que você colocou no exemplo ou deveria ser dinâmico para aceitar qualquer array?

Comment: Deveria ser dinâmico para aceitar qualquer estrutura de array, com dimensões e profundidade variadas.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que essa função atenda as suas necessidades

```
//&$default é o array a ser modificado, recebido como um parâmetro por referência e $data é o segundo array que irá sobrescrever o primeiro
function popule(&$default, $data){
    foreach($default as $key => &$item){ //percorremos todo o array usando sua posição como uma referência
        if(isset($data[$key])){ //verifica se a chave existe no segundo array
            if(is_array($item)){ //verifica se o índice em questão é um array
                popule($item, $data[$key]); //caso ele seja um array, envia para a mesma função para percorre-lo e procurar seus índices
            }else{
                $item = $data[$key]; //caso seja um valor, atribui o valor do segundo array ao primeiro
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A função percorre todo o primeiro array e comparando se os indices das duas são iguais, acessando recursivamente caso o índice seja um array ou atribuindo o valor do segundo ao primeiro caso seja um valor.

[Link dos testes realizados](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a01a443bb908e2fb82730e905ca27b2cbbac8218)

Comment: Obrigado JrD, resolveu perfeitamente pra mim.